# How to use RDS environment properties attached to Elastic Beanstalk Environment - Java

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an ElasticBeanstalk env with an RDS attached to it. The platform of the instance using Corretto 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2.

It says [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html) that the RDS settings are available as environment properties like `RDS_HOSTNAME` and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html#create_deploy_Java.rds.troubleshooting) it states that in Java, we could retrieve them using `System.getenv()`.

But when I try it on the EC2 instance, it returns `null`. Hence, when I use `${RDS_HOSTNAME}` in my application.properties file, the spring app fails to start.

[image]

I see one tutorial doing quite the same with what I do [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtDSJRdpJM4) but I could not figure out what is wrong with my settings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **export them first**. You can try the following as `root`:

```
export $(cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env | xargs)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. I am surprised that this critical step is not included in AWS document.

Comment: @D.T No problem. When your application runs, all the env variables are set. Its only problem when you want to do it "manually" after you ssh into the EB instance.